# JavaScript member function and main function in the same pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can a JavaScript pattern be written such that a function, e.g. log, can be invoked in the following two ways?

```
log.error('this is an error message');
log('this is a standard message');
```

---

I am aware that jQuery can be invoked like:

```
$('div').show();
```

as well as

```
$.extend()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context of these messages? Who has to see them, where and when?

Comment: `var log = function(m){...}; log.error = function(e) {...};` You want `log` to be a function, and you want it to have a property called `error` that is also a function. I suppose this might be difficult to conceptualize until you realize that functions in JS can have properties; after you understand this, it's completely trivial.

Comment: wow, that's actually super simple, thanks apsillers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is an object, you can assign properties to it. Those properties can be functions as well

```js
function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
log.error = function(message) {
   console.error(message)
}

log("Hello");
log.error("Error")
```